# Height of UIWebView minus 44px programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

Is it possible to set the height of a UIWebView by doing something like this..

```
[webView.height: currentHeight - 44px];
```

So essentially, I want to get the height of the UIWebView and then make it 44px shorter from the bottom, programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your old frame like this:

```
CGRect oldFrame = WebView.frame;
```

Then set the new frame :

```
CGRect newFrame =CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height-44);
[WebView setFrame:newFrame];
```

Thats it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be enough.

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height - 44);
```