# Why does this not change the size of the webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

This stackoverflow answer which is resolved doesnt seam to work for me and I have no idea why.

[Height of UIWebView minus 44px programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868668/height-of-uiwebview-minus-44px-programmatically?lq=1)

```
 CGRect oldFrame = WebView.frame;
    CGRect newFrame =CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height-44);
    [WebView setFrame:newFrame];
```

Comment: Is that actually called? Is `self.webView != nil`?

Comment: Check [this][1]

please check the link
Hope this helped

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868668/height-of-uiwebview-minus-44px-programmatically

Comment: @DrummerB if I call                                                  if (self.webView != nil)
NSLog(@"Yes"); Then this line is called

Comment: @ChiragPipaliya I tried that but it also doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once try like this after doing this one once reload the your webview ,

```
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, 0);
  [self.webView reload];
```