# Set height of UIWebView in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, resize, height

I have an UIWebView that I've added to the Storyboard via interface builder.
However I want to be able to change the height of the UIWebView within the code but I wan't been able to accomplish that by myself.

This is the code I tried to use which I was hoping that it would make the UIWebView shorter from the bottom.

```
CGRect oldFrame = WebView.frame;

CGRect newFrame =CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height-100);
[WebView setFrame:newFrame];
```

Comment: have you turned off Auto Layout feature in storyboard ?

Comment: or you can check out this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080084/why-does-this-not-change-the-size-of-the-webview)

Comment: Ah of course, the Auto Layout feature was still on! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. Please mark it as a correct so it can help others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please turn off Auto Layout feature in storyboard. this will solve your problem.